format input type number Thousand separator to 123.456.789
When user entering 123456 , user will look 123.456 in the input field.
I used my code but this display 123,456
What i want is exactly that Thousand separator is dot (not comma)
My code in link https://jsfiddle.net/bvotcode/tym4qf2r/3/
<form>
    <label for="ticketNum">Your  money</label>
    <input type="text" oninput="sepratornumberwithdot(this)"  placeholder="123.456.789"/>
</form>

function sepratornumberwithdot(input) {
    let nums = input.value.replace(/,/g, '');
    if (!nums || nums.endsWith('.')) return;
    input.value = parseFloat(nums).toLocaleString();
}

I tried using Javascript to adjust to dot but didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Normally we use toLocaleString() with one's country code, like this:
alert( (123456).toLocaleString('ja-JP') ); // Japanese


alert( (123456).toLocaleString('de-DE') ); // German

And so forth...
But if you're not happy use the German which does dots!

Change your first regular expression to /[,.]/g so that you get rid of commas and periods.
Add .replace(/,/g, '.') to the end of your .toLocaleString()
That will do it. See code snippet below:


function sepratornumberwithdot(input) {
  let nums = input.value.replace(/[,\.]/g, '');

  if (!nums || nums.endsWith('.')) return;
  input.value = parseFloat(nums).toLocaleString().replace(/,/g, '.');
}
form input {
  /* Keeps your number from moving around */
  text-align: end;
}
<form>
  <label for="ticketNum">Your  money</label>
  <input type="text" oninput="sepratornumberwithdot(this)"  placeholder="123.456.789"/> 
</form>




As @passThru pointed out, you could also change your toLocaleString() parameter instead of appending the .replace(). So the last javascript line would be:   input.value = parseFloat(nums).toLocaleString('de-DE');
You still need to change your first regular expression.
